# Mapping s-tab in vim

Tags: vim, vimrc, keymap

I'm trying to set up some basic configuration for vim to make it more useful for myself. One of the things I'm trying to do is map shift+tab to a literal tab character, since my vim configuration sets tabs to be expanded with spaces by default. I attempted to map  to the tab char using [this reference](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29) but no dice.

When I try to strike shift+tab whilst insert mode is active, vim outputs a capital Z for about one second, then removes it and drops out of insert mode with a system error beep. I already tested the shift+tab stroke with ^V and it output ^[[Z into vim as described in the reference, so it's not my OS hijacking the keystroke. Not exactly sure what's causing this; input would be appreciated.

My .vimrc:

```
" Few basic settings first; I like syntax highlighting & line numbers
syntax on
set number

" Some settings with the list option
" I like to see non-printing characters like Tab & CR
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬
set list

" Set tab behaviours: 4 spaces wide, expand <Tab> and >> with spaces
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
" This line maps shift+tab to a literal tab character
" Because I sometimes need a literal tab
set <s-tab>=
```

The very last line shows the ▸ character in vim when `set list` is on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
:set t_kB=^[[Z
```

You don't type the `^[` characters literally; to get the actual escape sequence press <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then press the escape key. Note that the `t_kB` option is the same as the `<S-Tab>` option.

However, this does not map `<S-Tab>` to `<Tab>`, it only tells Vim what escape sequence your terminal sends when you press those two keys. But at this point you can map `<S-Tab>` to `<Tab>`:

```
:noremap <S-Tab> <Tab>
```

To make Vim insert a literal tab character when an option like `'expandtab'` is set:

```
:inoremap <S-Tab> <C-V><Tab>
```

Comment: Just tried it and it still didn't work. :( shift+tab expanded into four spaces instead.

Comment: For the `noremap` command, did you type it exactly as it appears? Because you're meant to.  Also, what's output of "`:verbose set expandtab?`", with the question mark as part of the command.

Comment: Also, are you trying to insert a tab into the file, or are you trying to change `<S-Tab>` to behave like `<Tab>` in Vim. The answer matters.  If the latter, change `:noremap` to just `:map`.

Comment: I'm trying to change <S-Tab> so that it inserts a literal tab character into the file. <Tab> behaves as expected and indents the text with spaces.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to understand what you needed.  Yeah, you probably still need to set `t_tB`, but the mapping you need is: `:inoremap <S-Tab> <C-V><Tab>`

Comment: YES! Thank you so very much! :D That's exactly what I needed and it works perfectly!